# Stuck with epsilon-delta proof of existence of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Given $f(z):=f(x+iy) := u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, I'm trying to prove that if $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} f(z) = L$, where $L\in \mathbb{C}$, $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} u(x,y) = a$ and $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)} v(x,y) = b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Here's how I tried:

$\lvert z-z_0 \lvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(z)-L\lvert <\varepsilon$. So that $\lvert (x,y) - (x_0, y_0)\lvert < \delta$. Now, $\lvert u(x,y)+iv(x,y)-L\lvert=\lvert u(x,y) + iv(x,y)-\underbrace{(a+ib)}_L\lvert\le \lvert u(x,y)-a\lvert + \lvert v(x,y)-b\lvert$.

And that's where I'm stuck. I would appreciate if someone could please point out something peculiar that I'm not seeing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u(x,y),v(x,y),a$, and $b$ are all real numbers, you can actually compute $|f(z)-L|$ using the real and imaginary parts:
\begin{align*}
|f(z)-L|=|u(x,y)+iv(x,y)-(a+ib)| &= |u(x,y)-a+i(v(x,y)-b)|\\
&= \sqrt{(u(x,y)-a)^2 + (v(x,y)-b)^2}.
\end{align*}
Now by dropping the $(v(x,y)-b)^2$ or the $(u(x,y)-a)^2$, you get that the above quantity is greater than or equal to both $|u(x,y)-a|$ and $|v(x,y)-b|$.